# How do you shut down an Actor if it has not received a message within a period of time?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Current code is following:

```
case object LatestMessageSignal

class MessageCheckpoint(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor with ActorLogging with Timers {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case LatestMessageSignal => awaitLatestMessageSignal()
  }

  private def awaitLatestMessageSignal(): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(30.seconds) {
      context.stop(self)
    }
  }

}
```

When the actor receives a `LatestMessageSignal` message, it will call `awaitLatestMessageSignal()` method that will wait for 30 seconds, and then stop the actor.

Comment: Are you trying to stop the actor after 30 seconds of inactivity? If so, you can use `setReceiveTimeout` for that.

Comment: This question needs the title to be edited because what the questions's code does (and the answers answer) isn't related to the title at all. But I don't want to suggest any edits until you've had a chance to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you all for answers, I am sorry that my question was not clear.

The scenario is: 1) I would like to stop the actor when there is no new message received for 30 seconds. 2) When the actor has stopped, I would like to check if it has stopped.

Comment: You really do not have to check if it has stopped, if you call `context.stop(self)`, then it's stopped. If you really ant to see it for yourself, you could try sending a message to the actor after it's stopped (you should see a log entry about the message going into the "dead letters queue.")

Comment: I actually would like to be notified the stop of the actor from from outside an Actor. For example, when the actor has stopped after 30s of inactivity, from outside of the actor system, it should know the actor has stopped and then do something accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you want to stop the actor after 30 seconds of inactivity? If so you can use [`ActorContext#setReceiveTimeout(Duration)`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorContext.html#setReceiveTimeout(timeout:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):Unit)

For instance:

```
case object LatestMessageSignal

class MessageCheckpoint(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor with ActorLogging with Timers {

  context.setReceiveTimeout(30.seconds)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case ReceivedTimeout => context.stop(self)
  }

}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about this one. And quite shorter from what I suggested

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc our solutions are different, and it's not clear what the original question wants. My solution will reset the timeout on _any_ message, whereas yours resets only on `LatestMessageSignal`. I figured I'd put this alternative here in case that's adequate for the needs of the question poster.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you'd like to keep `MessageCheckpoint` alive and stop it if there are no new messages coming to it for 30 seconds.

This actor will stay alive till you send messages to it and will stop after 30 seconds of inactivity.

```scala
case object LatestMessageSignal

class MessageCheckpoint extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    super.postStop()
    log.info("Stopping")
  }

  override def receive: Receive = receiveWithTimer(None)

  private def receiveWithTimer(timer: Option[Cancellable]): Receive = {
    case LatestMessageSignal =>
      timer.foreach(_.cancel())
      context.become(receiveWithTimer(Option(initiateTimer())))
  }

  private def initiateTimer(): Cancellable = {
    import context.dispatcher
    log.info("Initiating new poison pill timer")
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(30.seconds, self, PoisonPill)
  }
}
```

> I would like the actor can discard current processing message when another new message comes, and will process the latest message instead

This is not possible. I think you are assuming that method `awaitLatestMessageSignal` is blocking the actor. This method is non blocking, it will create a timer and return immediately. The message will be processed quite fast and actor be ready for the next message. Actor is processing messages one at a time and there is no way to cancel message processing.